# How to fill area with our choice colour in plotly area grap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I want to change/fill area of plotly Area graph with our choice of colour instead of blue. But I'm unable to change it. I referred [This Code](https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/).

Graph is coming like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add [`fillcolor`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scattergl-fillcolor) to your data.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: ['Nov 2013', 'Dec 2013', 'Jan 2014', 'Feb 2014'],
  y: [2, 1, 3, 5],
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  type: 'scatter',
  fillcolor: 'red'
};

var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Comment: I putted this graph in div tag of my application. But its coming very small graph. I unable to increase width and height of draglayer.

Comment: Can you share your code or preferably open a new question?